# Angular component template is not updated with the value from observable

Tags: angular

I have a component that updates its state from a service observable:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SessionTimeoutService} from "./session-timeout/session-timeout.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-session-timeout-bar',
  templateUrl: './session-timeout-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./session-timeout-bar.component.scss']
})
export class SessionTimeoutBarComponent {
  public secondsToTimeout$: Observable<number | null> = this.sessionTimeoutService.secondsToTimeout$
  public showSessionTimeoutBar$: Observable<boolean> = this.sessionTimeoutService.secondsToTimeout$
    .map(secondsToTimeout => secondsToTimeout != null)

  constructor(private sessionTimeoutService: SessionTimeoutService) {
  }
}
```

and its template look like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="this.showSessionTimeoutBar$ | async">
  Logout in {{this.secondsToTimeout$ | async}} sec.
</div>
```

The problem is, that when the `secondsToTimeout$` emits `null` the template doesn't get that information and is stuck on the last valid number. When `secondsToTimeout$` starts to emit numbers again it gets these values then and adequately when again `null` is sent it blocks again on the last number.
I tried to subscribe to it manually, force detect changes, nothing really comes to my mind.

The detect changes strategy is set to onPush.

I asked 4 ppl in the company and they also think that this should really work.
Please help as I run out of ideas.

@edit

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {EventTargetInterruptSource, Idle} from "@ng-idle/core";
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class SessionTimeoutService {

  private readonly numberOfSecondsLeftWhenTimeoutBarShouldOccur = 55;
  private secondsToTimeout: BehaviorSubject<number | null> = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
  public secondsToTimeout$: Observable<number | null> = this.secondsToTimeout.asObservable();

  constructor(private idle: Idle) {
    this.initiateIdleSubscriptions();
    this.configureSessionTimeout(1)
  }

  private initiateIdleSubscriptions(): void {
    this.idle.setInterrupts([new EventTargetInterruptSource(document, 'click')]);
    this.idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
      this.secondsToTimeout.next(null);
    });
    this.idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('idling')
    })
    this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((secondsLeft: number) => {
      this.secondsToTimeout.next(secondsLeft)
    });
    this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('onTimeout')
    });
  }

  private configureSessionTimeout(sessionLengthInMinutes: number): void {
    const howLongTheyCanBeInactiveBeforeIdle = this.howLongTheyCanBeInactiveBeforeIdle(sessionLengthInMinutes);
    this.idle.setIdle(howLongTheyCanBeInactiveBeforeIdle);
    this.idle.setTimeout(this.numberOfSecondsLeftWhenTimeoutBarShouldOccur);
    this.idle.watch();
  }

  private howLongTheyCanBeInactiveBeforeIdle(sessionLengthMinutes: number): number {
    return sessionLengthMinutes * 60 - this.numberOfSecondsLeftWhenTimeoutBarShouldOccur;
  }
}
```

We have still angular 9.0.4^ in the project.

I was able to reproduce it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-9-web-app-forked-vklg4h

Comment: Hey ! Could you provide some code of the "secondsToTimeout" observable from your service ?

Comment: Hey! Yeah sure. Please see the updated question. I cropped some parts like config loading and logging out, but the main thing is there we used `ng-idle` library for that.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-9-web-app-forked-vklg4h

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for the sandbox, I managed to find the issue with it.

It seems that your `this.secondsToTimeout.next(null);` is never called, thus the `null` value never reaches your template.

If you put it inside the `onTimeout` instead of `onIdleEnd`, it should work

```js
this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
 this.secondsToTimeout.next(null);
});
```

Comment: @NieMaszNic can you confirm it solves your problem ? :)